# Spring bean depends on a conditional bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want a spring bean to be instanciated **after another bean**. So I simply use the `@DependsOn` annotation.

The thing is : this other bean is a conditional bean wearing the
`@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "some.property", havingValue = "true")` annotation.
So when the property is false then the bean is not instanciated (and that's what we want), and the `@DependsOn` obviously fails. The goal here is : create the second bean anyway, but create it after the first one **if it was created**.

Is there a way to do that without removing the `@ConditionalOnProperty` ? And without playing with the `@Order` annotation ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Same problem but have to be honest that it's because of poor modelling of the suite of contexts that are used across different variants of the application. This would have been a further "quick fix" to avoid the real issue :)

Answer (score 8):

How about the following approach:

```
interface Something {}

public class FirstBean implements Something {}

public class SecondBean implements Something{} // maybe empty implementation
```

Now the configuration goes like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

  @Bean(name = "hello")
  @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "some.property", havingValue = true) 
  public Something helloBean() {
     return new FirstBean();
  }

  @Bean(name = "hello")
  @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "some.property", havingValue = false) 
  public Something secondBean() {
     return new SecondBean();
  }

  @Bean
  @DependsOn("hello")
  public MyDependantBean dependantBean() {
       return new MyDependantBean();
  }
}
```

The idea is to create the "Something" bean anyway (even if its an empty implementation), so that the dependant bean will depend on Something in any case.

I've not tried this myself, you know, spring is full of magic, but probably it worth a try:)

Comment: I'd like to avoid creating the conditional bean in both cases. The question is all about producing clean code here. I am probably too demanding. Yes indeed your solution would work as needed :).

Comment: I saw solutions like this a couple of times in spring boot code itself so I've borrowed an idea from there: don't really remember where exactly, but they do sometimes create no-op beans for various purposes

Comment: You really don't need the "Something" interface. I have a similar setup but I just use an Object for the mock bean since anyway @DependsOn works on bean name.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `@DependsOn` you can use `@AutoConfigureAfter()`which will allow the second bean to be created even if the first bean was not created, but still keep the order.

```
@Configuration
public class FirstConfiguration {

  @Bean(name = "firstBean")
  @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "some.property", havingValue = true) 
  public FirstBean firstBean() {
     return new FirstBean();
  }
}

@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(name = {"firstBean"})
public class SecondConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public SecondBean secondBean() {
       return new SecondBean();
  }
}
```

Comment: It's disappointing to find out that the `@AutoConfigureAfter` annotation doesn't apply to methods.

Comment: This annotation also does not help with  bean creation order as stated in the docs: As with standard Configuration classes, the order in which auto-configuration classes are applied only affects the order in which their beans are defined. The order in which those beans are subsequently created is unaffected and is determined by each bean's dependencies and any DependsOn relationships.

Answer (score 3):

Could you create two definitions for the dependent bean, to cater for the two cases where the other bean is or isn't there?

E.g.:

```
@Bean(name = "myDependentBean")
@DependsOn("otherBean")
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "some.property", havingValue = true) 
public DependentBean myDependentBean() {
    return new DependentBean();
}

@Bean(name = "myDependentBean")
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "some.property", havingValue = false, matchIfMissing = true) 
public DependentBean myDependentBean_fallback() {
    return new DependentBean();
}
```

(This is the approach I've just taken today to solve a similar problem!)

Then Spring would use the first definition if `some.property` is `true`, and so instantiate `myDependentBean` after `otherBean`. If `some.property` is missing or `false`, Spring will use the second definition, and so not care about `otherBean`.

Alternatively, you could probably use `@ConditionalOnBean`/`@ConditionalOnMissingBean` on these, instead of `@ConditionalOnProperty` (though I've not tried this).

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom condition class:

```
public class BeanPresennceCondition implements Condition {

  @Override
  public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
      FirstBean firstBean = null;
      try {
      firstBean = (FirstBean)context.getBeanFactory().getBean("firstBean"); 
      }catch(NoSuchBeanDefinitionException ex) {

      }
     return firstBean != null;
  }
}
```

Comment: On what bean ? The second one ? This would just instanciate the second bean if the first one exists .. That is not what I want. I might have not got your point though